# Selenium Webdriver for loop opens many browsers, does not wait for function to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the following code, 150 browsers are instantly opened to google.com. How can I make the loop wait until the function finishes before opening google again?

```
const {
    Builder, By, Key, until
} = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');

for (let index = 0; index < 150; index++) {
    (async function example() {
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
        try {
            await driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } finally {
            await driver.quit();
        }
    })();
}
```

I tried using code from the following posts but had no luck:
[JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous),
[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa),
[make async call inside forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178868/make-async-call-inside-foreach?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Thanks in advance for any help or info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declaring and executing an `async` function doesn't automatically make the thread wait until the function executes - you have to `await` it as well, otherwise it's interpreted simply as a declared promise.

```
(async () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < 150; index++) {
    await (async function example() {
      let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
      try {
        await driver.get('https://www.google.com/');
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } finally {
        await driver.quit();
      }
    })();
  }
})();
```